# How to convert an HTML5 and JQuery featured E-book to an Executable file(exe), having inbuilt browser?

Tags: conversion, html, ebook-management

I want to distribute the e-book content, which has some HTML5 and Jquery features, securely by converting the whole HTML package into an EXE. 
Does any HTML Compiling software exists which has its own inbuilt browser and runs the majority of HTML5 and Jquery?

I have already tried and tested HTML Executable 4. But it's internal browser is very outdated and don't support HTML 5 or Jquery.

Comment: Even if you could -- why on earth would you want to do that?! ("Securely"? I don't think I would touch touch an `exe` with Linux...)

Comment: I don't know of existing applications that can do that, but it's possible to write such application (there are components for embedding Chrom or Chromium into a .Net application). Why not just leave the ebook as html though?

Answer (score 2):

You actually want to build HTML5-based standalone desktop apps. You should try:

- App.js (http://appjs.com/)
- Tide SDK (http://www.tidesdk.org/)
- Node webkit (https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit)

I don't know how well they play together with JQuery, or with already written eBooks, but you can make a try.

Actually many times the point with this packages is that you can develop multi-platform (i.e not exporting in EXE is the end all be all)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Node-WebKit: https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps

I heard Adobe AIR can generate EXE files for Windows, but I cannot confirm first-hand: http://www.adobe.com/products/air/